# Retornar resto de um array em outro array

Tags: javascript, array

Nesse código estou retornando os valores que se repetem no array de cada letra, resultando essa saída:
Exemplo de saída:
"14B2A3C2D"

Mas preciso tambem que caso alguma letra seja maior que 9, o resto seja mostrada em outro indice, ficando com essa saida:
Exemplo de saída:
"9B5B2A3C2D"

Tentei usar com split mas não deu muito certo, segue o código:

```
var stringAlvo = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBAACCCDD'
var frase = Array.from(stringAlvo)

const VERIFICADOR_LETRAS = 'BACD'
let letras = []
let contador = 0

function contadorLetras() {
  for (let i = 0; i < VERIFICADOR_LETRAS.length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < frase.length; k++) {
      if (VERIFICADOR_LETRAS[i] == frase[k]) {
        contador++
      }
    }
    if (contador > 0) {
      letras[VERIFICADOR_LETRAS[i]] = contador
    }
    contador = 0
  }

  return letras
}

console.log(contadorLetras())
```

Comment: Em vez de fazer isso no array, quebre o valor apenas na hora de gerar a string. Na verdade, acho que nem precisa de array: https://ideone.com/91bbSg

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma possível solução para esse problema é criar um objeto auxiliar com a contagem das letras. E posteriormente montar a string como desejado, tratando a contagem de letras acima de 9.

Segue exemplo funcional abaixo.

```js
const transformador = (texto) => {
  const dicionario = {};

  for (const letra of texto) {
    const quantidadeEncontrada = dicionario[letra] || 0;
    dicionario[letra] = quantidadeEncontrada + 1;
  }

  let textoResultante = "";
  Object.entries(dicionario).forEach(([letra, quantidade]) => {
    while (quantidade > 0) {
      const valorASerPrintado = Math.min(quantidade, 9);
      textoResultante += `${valorASerPrintado}${letra}`;
      quantidade -= valorASerPrintado;
    }
  });

  return textoResultante;
}

console.log(transformador("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBAACCCDD")); // 9B5B2A3C2D
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!